# Flask: Blueprint not showing custom error page

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Here is how i am creating a simple blueprint

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

my_bp_page = Blueprint('my_bp_page', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@my_bp_page.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html', pageName='my_bp_page.home')


@my_bp_page.route('/home', methods=['GET'], strict_slashes=False)
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

and here is my `404.html`

```
{% block title %}Page Not Found{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
  <p>What you were looking for is just not there.
  <p>
    {% if pageName is defined %}
        <a href="{{ url_for(pageName) }}">Go Back</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Go Back</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

while testing this, i tried the URL `localhost:5000/home/junk` and i see

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

this is not what i should see. I should be seeing my custom `404.html`

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that as far as Flask is concerned, the `/home/junk` path does not belong to your `my_bp_page` blueprint. It is just a path for which no route has been registered.

This caveat is mentioned in the [Error Handlers](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/#error-handlers) section of the Blueprints documentation (3rd paragraph).

The recommended solution is to use an app-level error handler, and inspect `request.path` to customise the way errors are handled.

Comment: makes sense. how can i write a global handler for all `404` requests ? can i put some regex in the api path/route ?

Comment: Just look at the bottom of the page I linked above, the example is a global error handler